# Incompleteness theorem validity on assertions with no referential cycles

Tags: logic, incompleteness

Popularized expositions of the Gödel Incompleteness theorem typically show the theorem to rely on a self-referential assertion that cannot be proved from the existing axioms.

Self-referential assertions are known to be *problematic* as they can lead to verbal paradoxes as [Russell's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox)

Hence this leads me to question: Consider the subset of mathematical assertions that have referential cycles (i.e. their assertions have references that can lead to the original assertion), not sure if this subset has a customary name in the field, but let's call it the set of self-cyclic assertions $\bf{SC}$. Now consider the complement of this set ($\bf{SC^\complement}$), which might include assertions that have references that can be mapped to some [directed acyclic graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph).

**Questions in my mind:**

1) is $\bf{SC^\complement}$ a well-defined set? one in which one or more assertions can either belong to it or not in a provable way

2) Does the Incompleteness theorem still apply to assertions in $\bf{SC^\complement}$?

## Addendum

It seems that the notion of reference of assertions is ill-defined as long as many assertions with the same amount of information are formally different assertions.

Consider the assertion (think of $P$ as a Gödel index)

- $P$: *Assertion $P$ is false*

And consider now these two assertions (again, think of $M$ and $N$ as a Gödel indices):

- $M$: *Assertion $N$ is false*
- $N$: *Assertion $M$ is false*

Ideally, one should be able to define an equivalence class for assertions identity such that one can "quotient" the two assertions $M$ and $N$ into being identical to $P$. Tentatively I would hope that such equivalence $E(M) = E(N) = E(P)$ would make $\bf{SC} \Big/ E$ (and its complement) well-defined sets

Comment: It is worth pointing out that there are proofs of both the first and second incompleteness theorems that revolve around Kolmogoroff complexity, and do not invoke self-reference or diagonal constructions in any way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The obvious problem with this idea is, how exactly do you define **SC**? The whole point of Godel's theorem is that we can hide self-reference inside purely arithmetic statements - we may *think of* the Godel sentence as saying "This sentence is unprovable" ([or similar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosser%27s_trick)), but the sentence is really "just" a statement about numbers and arithmetic.

- In particular, there isn't actually any "referential structure" in the sentence itself - that's a component of *our analysis of* the sentence.

The [MRDP theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_set) pushes this to a further level: the theorem *(or rather, the proof of the theorem + a little bit of auxiliary argument)* shows that for every appropriate theory $T$ there is a Diophantine equation $\mathcal{E}_T$ such that $\mathcal{E}_T$ has no solutions but $T$ cannot prove that $\mathcal{E}_T$ has no solutions. Sentences of the form $$\forall x_1,...,x_n(f(x_1,...,x_n)\not=0)$$ are about as concrete as it gets, yet by the above observation wind up yielding incompleteness.

Put another way, **there is no clear culprit for incompleteness**. That isn't to say that there aren't reasonably-large decidable subtheories of a given theory (e.g. [addition without multiplication is decidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presburger_arithmetic)), but this basically kills the hope of restricting incompleteness to the "unnatural" sentences.

Comment: hi @Noah thanks for the answer. In MRDP, does there exist a computable map from every theory $T$ to the coefficients that define $\mathcal{E}_T$ such that satisfy the theorem? Otherwise, it seems to me that one could argue that the definition of $\mathcal{E}_T$ has an implicit recursion in it. Btw, I added an addendum regarding your comments

Comment: @lurscher Yes, the map $T\mapsto\mathcal{E}_T$ is computable in the appropriate sense.

Comment: +1 I guessed the author of this answer before I reached the end of the first paragraph.

Comment: @lurscher re: your addendum, the problem is still that the sentences you're writing aren't actually sentences of arithmetic (in fact, by [Tarski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_undefinability_theorem) they can't be since they refer to truth values directly). So that addendum still isn't addressing the real core issue: how do we uncover the "referential content" of a sentence which, on the face of it, just talks about numbers and arithmetic?

Comment: I'm not sure about the following: when you say *the sentence is really "just" a statement about numbers and arithmetic.* the statements are not on concrete numbers directly, but implicitly rely on a *particular Gödel encoding* from which the number will refer to the assertion. So I still think that one could narrow down more such assertions as having a hidden cycle in their definitions

Comment: @lurscher No, they are statements about concrete numbers directly. When we whip one up we have a specific Godel numbering in mind, but the actual sentence resulting is just a very concrete, if really long, sentence about arithmetic. (Keep in mind that the sentence is separate from its motivation and discovery - *how* we found it doesn't affect *what* it is.)

Comment: @Ethan Noah is definitely an MSE style icon IMO.